# Java HtmlUnit Save a Image and Replace text

Tags: java, htmlunit

I have a list of pictures here:

```
     List<HtmlImage> picsa = (List<HtmlImage>) myPageww.getByXPath("//img[@alt]");
```

Then I save picture for picture:

```
 for (int i2 = 0; i2 < picsa.size(); i2++) {
                            File imageFile = new File(dir + "/" + "bilder/" + i2 + ".jpg");
                            imageFile.mkdirs();

                            picsa.get(i2).saveAs(imageFile);
```

}

now my problem is, the list of pictures have a src=url......$_00.JPG

and I must change the $_00.JPG to $_000.JPG

but if I try to replace it

```
HtmlImage imageCap = picsa.get(i2).asText().replace("$_00", "$_000");
```

I become an error

> incompatible types: String cannot be converted to HtmlImage

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

`asText()` returns a `String`. `replace()` is a method of `String` and returns a `String`. You try to assign a `String` value to `HtmlImage`, which is not possible.

Your variable `imageCap` should be a `String`.